# R Summary to parsable format preferable JSON

Tags: json, r

Is there a way to get a clean output from `summary(df)` as JSON or a dataframe where not everything has excess whitespace and the actual things like "Min: 3" are in one column? I would like to have something like this:

```
[
    {
        "column1": {
            "Min": 1,
            "Max": 3,
            "3rd Qu": 5
            ...
        }
    },

    {
        "column2": {
            "Min": 2,
            "Max": 4,
            "3rd Qu": 5,
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Checkout the [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of options for converting to JSON, but you first need to get your data into a format that will convert the way you want (or at all). Thus, it's easiest to assemble the summary as a list so you can determine the hierarchy of the JSON. Using piping and `purrr::map` (like `lapply`) for readability:

```
library(purrr)

iris %>% map(summary) %>%    # make a list of summaries in case both numeric/factor
    map(as.list) %>%     # coerce each summary to a list
    jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)   # convert to JSON, make it legible
```

which returns

```
{
  "Sepal.Length": {
    "Min.": 4.3,
    "1st Qu.": 5.1,
    "Median": 5.8,
    "Mean": 5.843,
    "3rd Qu.": 6.4,
    "Max.": 7.9
  },
  "Sepal.Width": {
    "Min.": 2,
    "1st Qu.": 2.8,
    "Median": 3,
    "Mean": 3.057,
    "3rd Qu.": 3.3,
    "Max.": 4.4
  },
  "Petal.Length": {
    "Min.": 1,
    "1st Qu.": 1.6,
    "Median": 4.35,
    "Mean": 3.758,
    "3rd Qu.": 5.1,
    "Max.": 6.9
  },
  "Petal.Width": {
    "Min.": 0.1,
    "1st Qu.": 0.3,
    "Median": 1.3,
    "Mean": 1.199,
    "3rd Qu.": 1.8,
    "Max.": 2.5
  },
  "Species": {
    "setosa": 50,
    "versicolor": 50,
    "virginica": 50
  }
}
```

If you'd don't pipe, you can do it without `purrr`:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(lapply(iris, function(x){as.list(summary(x))}), pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

which returns the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain why lapply is needed on the dataframe?

Comment: If you just call `as.list(summary(iris))`, it won't give you the hierarchy you want, with each column as an element, and will insert `NA`s if some summaries are longer than others. In short, it's easier to convert several small summaries to the form you need than one larger, more complicated one.